# Controlling access to directories in ftp server - ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, server

i want to users like u1,u2,u3 can login to ftp
and can upload,change files in /myftp sub folders.

u1 should have access to /myftp/folder1
u2 should have access to /myftp/folder1 and /myftp/folder2
u3 should have access to /myftp/ all folders
anonym should not access to /myftp/folder3 !

is it possible?
i’m using vsftpd.
Help me Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible, but it is very long process and follow the steps.

1. supposing  u created users and their home directories.
2. create folder1 in each and every user like u1,u2,u3 and also in /myftp/folder1
3. then mount and bind these folders

   sudo mount --bind  /home/u1/e-Books /home/myftp/folder1

   sudo mount --bind  /home/u2/e-Books /home/myftp/folder1

   sudo mount --bind  /home/u3/e-Books /home/myftp/folder3
4. then enter in fstab, for folder structure to remain after reboots

   sudo nano /etc/fstab

add below line

```
/home/u1/e-Books  /home/myftp/folder1    none    bind    0       0
/home/u2/e-Books /home/myftp/folder1     none    bind    0       0
/home/u3/e-Books /home/myftp/folder3     none    bind    0       0
```

5. install acl

   sudo apt-get install acl
   then Add the option acl to the partition(s) on which you want to enable ACL in /etc/fstab, like below example.

   UUID=07aebd28-24e3-cf19-e37d-1af9a23a45d4    /home    ext4   defaults,acl   0   2

then verify whether acl is enabled or not by

6. add u1,u2,u3 in various groups

7.Now u can give permissions for folder as per your requirement by following command with groups criteria

```
sudo setfacl -m g:groupname:rwx /myftp/folder1/
```

8. now you can do this process for as many user and folders as u want.

note- please mark my answer as correct if u find it use full. feel free to ask doubts. i configured this setup recently and it is perfectly working.